# Unknown TLS protocol detected on network

Tags: tls

We've detected an unknown protocol attempting to communicate on port 443 on our network. The first five bytes are:

[67 66 75 80 80]

I haven't been able to match this up with any known TLS protocol but perhaps I've missed something. As reference, the first five bytes of TLS 1.2 are:

First byte: Content Type - typically 22 (Handshake)

2-3: Protocol version

4-5: cipher length - max allowed is 16384. Length above (80, 80) equals 20,560.

Question: What is this protocol?

For clarity, these are the first five bytes of the (possible) ClientHello portion of the TLS handshake.

Edit 2: Here's the full message being transmitted (in decimal):

67 66 75 80 80 82 5 80 70 2 54 0 0 0 0 208 45 246 211 76 241 199 209 119 166 249 155 90 161 37 74 180 147 167 229 45 169 151 37 41 5 98 128 154 101 134 242 105 139 201 35 8 14 78 222 188 96 64 26 151 133 163 92 148 135 172 237 253

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. It is clear that this is not some "unknown TLS protocol" - it is not TLS at all. It simply is something which is using port 443 for non-TLS traffic. This might be an error or it might be an attempt to pass through firewalls which often have port 443 simply open and don't do any kind of traffic inspection there. But I doubt that one can say from the few information provided what it actually is. And I'm not sure that you  actually want to know this - your question contains only statements but there is no explicit question.

Comment: That's `C B K P P` -- possibly someone/something mistakenly sending plaintext. And you mean for all TLS (and obsolete/broken SSLv3) _five_ bytes are 1=type, 2-3=version, 4-5=length. (No one expects the Spanish Inquisition! Our chief weapon is surprise! And fear! ....)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Correct, it is definitely not TLS (when I wrote the question title, I was not sure of that). My best guess right now is that it is a device of some kind utilizing a custom protocol on port 443. I'd like to know what the protocol is and ideally, identify the device.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Good catch. The first set of bytes (up to 0 0 0 0) are "CBKPPRPF6". I've pasted the full message above.

Comment: @WinstonPrivacy: I don't know any protocol which starts this way. It is not even clear if this just a coincidence that the message started this way and that further parts of the protocol or new connections will look completely different. I If you want to know more please collect more data (capture packets as pcap with `tcpdump` or similar). If the source of the traffic is the internal network analyze the source system to find out what exactly is sending the traffic - maybe some malware is trying to phone home.

Answer (score 2):

We solved it. This was a proprietary protocol used by Honeywell in their alarm systems. They are sending it over port 443, which is a terribly bad idea as their documentation states they have problems with many different routers (because of it).

I wish I could say that we figured this out in some elegant manner. I proceeded by trapping the failed TLS/ClientHello message, then looked up the original destination in the conntrac tables. A reverse IP lookup indicated that this was owned by AlarmNet, which then led to us experimenting with turning network interception on/off while observing the alarm system. Just old fashioned detective work and elbow grease.

Comment: Great job identifying an unknown protocol using TCP443. How about updating your answer with more details on how you arrived at this result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is TLS, looks like someone is miss configure a system that use that protocol to connect to your systems basically, It would be nice if you could upload the pcap file with the TCP connection for understand a bit more the unknown protocol if needed

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to use pcap (sounds useful, never had the time). I'm grabbing these bytes directly off the wire.

Comment: May be I didn't explain my self correctly, a pcap file is basically is a file that contains the network packets from network interfaces. You can generate them with the well known tools like tcpdump and wireshark